# How do I utilize a named instance within the ObjectFactory.Initialize call for StructureMap?

Tags: vb.net, structuremap

I am trying to do the following bootstrapping:

```
            x.For(Of IErrorLogger).Use(Of ErrorLogger.SQLErrorLogger)().
                Ctor(Of IErrorLogger)("backupErrorLogger").Is(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(Of IErrorLogger)("Disk"))

            x.For(Of IErrorLogger).Add(
                Function()
                    Return New ErrorLogger.DiskErrorLogger(
                        CreateErrorFileName(ServerMapPath(GetAppSetting("ErrorLogFolder"))))
                End Function).Named("Disk")
```

But it shows this error:

StructureMap Exception Code:  200
Could not find an Instance named "Disk" for PluginType Logging.IErrorLogger

I sort of understand why this is happening.. the question is, how do I utilize a named instance within the registry? Maybe something like lazy initialization for the ctor argument for the SQLErrorLogger? I am not sure how to make it happen.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct way to do it in the latest version (2.6.1) of StructureMap:

```
x.For(Of IErrorLogger).Use(Of ErrorLogger.SQLErrorLogger)().
    Ctor(Of IErrorLogger)("backupErrorLogger").Is(
        Function(c) c.ConstructedBy(Function() ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(Of IErrorLogger)("Disk"))
        )

x.For(Of IErrorLogger).Add(Function() _
        New ErrorLogger.DiskErrorLogger(
            CreateErrorFileName(ServerMapPath(GetAppSetting("ErrorLogFolder"))))
        ).Named("Disk")
```

Notice for the Is method of Ctor, we need to provide a func(IContext), and use the IContext.ConstructedBy(Func()) to call ObjectFactory.Get... to successfully register the IErrorLogger in this case.

This is the only way to do it as far as I know. The other Icontext methods such as IsThis and Instance will only work with already registered type.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access the Container before it's configured. In order to make structuremap evaluate the object resolution after the configuration you need to provide a lambda to the `Is` function. The lambda will be evaluated when trying to resolve the type registered.

```
x.[For](Of ILogger)().Add(Of SqlLogger)().Ctor(Of ILogger)("backupErrorLogger")_
    .[Is](Function(context) context.GetInstance(Of ILogger)("Disk"))
x.[For](Of ILogger)().Add(Of DiskLogger)().Ctor(Of String)("errorFileName")_
    .[Is](CreateErrorFileName(ServerMapPath(GetAppSetting("ErrorLogFolder"))))_
    .Named("Disk")
```

Disclaimer: I'm not completely up-to-date with the lambda syntax in VB.NET, but I hope I got it right.

**Edit:**

The working C# version of this I tried myself before posting was this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(i =>
            {
                i.For<ILogger>().Add<SqlLogger>()
                    .Ctor<ILogger>("backup").Is(
                        c => c.GetInstance<ILogger>("disk"))
                    .Named("sql");
                i.For<ILogger>().Add<DiskLogger>().Named("disk");
            });

var logger = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ILogger>("sql");
```

Comment: I believe you meant to use context."Instance" instead. This wouldn't work for the same reason in my question. I provided my answer with a brief explanation.

Comment: I translated this from a C# spike I did and that worked perfectly. What's not working with this? Are you getting a 200? See my edit for the code I tried and got working.